# Неверный вывод функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Мне необходимо сделать, чтобы выводилось всегда наибольшее количество символов до определенной буквы, сейчас выводится почему-то наименьшее, хотя до буквы "s" больше символов, но выводится количество символов до буквы "g", но если их поменять местами, то выведется наибольшее, то есть до "s", помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

```
const func = (s, a, b) => {
        let aIndex = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(a));
        let bIndex = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(b));
    
        if ((aIndex.length != s.length) < (bIndex.length != s.length)) {
          if (s.includes(a) && s.includes(b)) {
            return ((s != "" && a != "" && b != "")) || ((s.includes(a) || s.includes(b)) && s != "" && (a != "" || b != "")) ? bIndex.length : -1;
          } return -1
        } return ((s.includes(a) && s.includes(b)) && (s != "" && a != "" && b != "")) || ((s.includes(a) || s.includes(b)) && s != "" && (a != "" || b != "")) ? aIndex.length : -1;
      };
    
      console.log(func("aafghjjkfjbbddddsafv", "g", "s"));
```

Comment: Попробуйте описать словами что делает этот код. Я сломался на этой строчке `if ((aIndex.length != s.length) < (bIndex.length != s.length)) `

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, и вам нужно вернуть кол-во символов саммой длинной подстроки, от начала и до символа, то вот примерный код для вашей задачи:

```js
function getMaxCharsCount(str, ch1, ch2) {
  const strBeforeChar1 = str.split(ch1)[0]
  const strBeforeChar2 = str.split(ch2)[0]
  
  if(strBeforeChar1.length > strBeforeChar2.length ) {
    return strBeforeChar1.length
  }
  
  return strBeforeChar2.length
}

console.log(getMaxCharsCount("aafghjjkfjbbddddsafv", "g", "s"));
```

Comment: Привет, твой код верен, но, если к примеру символ повторяется, то он должен вернуть количество до этого символа, то есть если "abbbbb", то он вернет количество символов до последней буквы b, то есть цифру 5, а при твоём решении он возвращает 1